# Programmatically run vaadin extesion

Tags: java, vaadin

I try to run FileDownLoader by this way:

```
FileDownLoader fd = new FileDownLoader {
// ... code
}

Button exportButton = new Button();
fd.extend(exportButton);

// code...
```

When I click on button in application file downloads well.
But when I click it programmatically nothing happens:

```
exportButton.click();
```

Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileDownLoader` starts file downloading only when it's clicked on by the user, meaning that you cannot trigger it from your code. Reason for this is that some browser show security warnings when download is started from indirect user action.